# POSTFIX bouncing when destination is my domain

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am using provider mail hosting to send emails. On my Webserver I also have Postfix running and configured. Here is my *main.cf*

---

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = yes
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
myhostname = 2-5-8.bih.net.ba
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = bhcom.info, 2-5-8.bih.net.ba, localhost.bih.net.ba, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 10485760
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 80.65.85.114
```

---

When I try sending email to my hosted domain name, every message gets bounced with this error:

```
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/pickup[802]: 1492A3E0C6C: uid=0 from=<razvoj@bhcom.info>
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/cleanup[988]: 1492A3E0C6C: message-id=<20121104193834.1492A3E0C6C@2-5-8.bih.net.ba>
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/qmgr[803]: 1492A3E0C6C: from=<razvoj@bhcom.info>, size=348, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/local[990]: 1492A3E0C6C: to=<info@bhcom.info>, relay=local, delay=0.12, delays=0.08/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "info")
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/cleanup[988]: 28ED53E0C6D: message-id=<20121104193834.28ED53E0C6D@2-5-8.bih.net.ba>
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/qmgr[803]: 28ED53E0C6D: from=<>, size=2056, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/bounce[991]: 1492A3E0C6C: sender non-delivery notification: 28ED53E0C6D
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/qmgr[803]: 1492A3E0C6C: removed
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/local[990]: 28ED53E0C6D: to=<razvoj@bhcom.info>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "razvoj")
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/qmgr[803]: 28ED53E0C6D: removed
```

However, when I try to @gmail.com, it sends message without problems, and here is log. What might be the issue?

```
Nov  4 20:41:23 2-5-8 postfix/pickup[802]: B2EC63E0C6C: uid=0 from=<razvoj@bhcom.info>
Nov  4 20:41:23 2-5-8 postfix/cleanup[1022]: B2EC63E0C6C: message-id=<20121104194123.B2EC63E0C6C@2-5-8.bih.net.ba>
Nov  4 20:41:23 2-5-8 postfix/qmgr[803]: B2EC63E0C6C: from=<razvoj@bhcom.info>, size=350, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  4 20:41:23 2-5-8 postfix/smtp[1024]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4001:c02::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Nov  4 20:41:24 2-5-8 postfix/smtp[1024]: B2EC63E0C6C: to=<amerzec@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.70.26]:25, delay=0.97, delays=0.08/0.01/0.27/0.62, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1352058066 f7si2180442eeo.46)
Nov  4 20:41:24 2-5-8 postfix/qmgr[803]: B2EC63E0C6C: removed
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the log says it:

```
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/local[990]: 1492A3E0C6C: to=<info@bhcom.info>, relay=local, delay=0.12, delays=0.08/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "info")
Nov  4 20:38:34 2-5-8 postfix/local[990]: 28ED53E0C6D: to=<razvoj@bhcom.info>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "razvoj")
```

You have no local user `info` and no `razvoj` the local delivery could deliver mail to.
If I understood your post correctly, you do want to send mail from that machine, but this is not your mail server where you want to receive and read it, right?

If it's correct, just drop `bhcom.info` from `mydestination` and everything should be fine.

A bit of background: every hostname listed in `mydestination` is considered local by Postfix and then itr tries to deliver the mail to that local user, which in your case does not exists.

Comment: Yes, this is my machine serving website which needs to be able to send email. That was absolutely correct. Thanks for background.

Comment: BTW, I would recommend configuring Postfix to send mail over your providers mailservers if that's possible. Some receiving servers have very crude rules for allowing mail and sending from the "official" server for your domain might help here :)

The configuration option is `relayhost`, the internet has some docs on that topic :)

Answer (score -2):

Also make sure you have all the packages needed.  I had relayhost all set up properly in main.cf, but was getting relay=none until I did this (on Ubuntu 14.04):

`apt-get install mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules`

Not sure why this fixed it.  The above came from a postfix relaying HOWTO at [easyengine.io](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/).

Comment: Please explain why installing sasl package solves bouncing problem with **unknown user** error?

Comment: That was a swipe from a HOWTO that fixed it for me.  Not sure why.  Postfix was missing something that allowed it to understand the relayhost stuff in my .cf  and would just give me relay=none and thus unknown user.